# Derivation of summation

Tags: derivatives, summation

What is the derivation of below summation with respect to "x" ?

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin^n x $$

this is what I've achieved so far:

$$ f(x)' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(\cos x)(\sin^nx)}{\sin x} $$

where to go from here?

the final answer is: $$\frac{\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}$$

Comment: Apply formula for Infinite GP in f(x)

Comment: Your better bet is to first sum the original series. (It is a geometric series after all!) Then differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x = (2k+1)\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\sin x = \pm 1$ and thus the sum doesn't converge. Otherwise $|\sin x| < 1$, so that you can apply the formula for geometric series, i.e.
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} \sin^n x = \frac{1}{1 - \sin x},
$$
hence
$$
f'(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1 - \sin x}\right)' = \frac{\cos x}{(1 - \sin x)^2}
$$